# CSS -webkit-appearance: none; is causing checkbox to not be checked

Tags: css

I have a checkbox that I applied the following CSS style to:

```css
-webkit-appearance: none;
```

This same code is on some text fields I have and these still continue to work just fine. Why is this functionality causing the checkbox to not allowed to be checked?

I like the styling of the checkbox this way but still need the functionality to work. If I change the code to:

```css
-webkit-appearance: checkbox;
```

It displays the standard checkbox. Any ideas? Here is a demonstration:

```css
/* http://jsfiddle.net/VWC76/ */

input[type='checkbox'] {
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #B5B7B8;
  font: 14px/26px 'pt-sans', 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;
  padding: 7px 7px 7px 12px;
  /*margin:0 0 30px 0;*/
  
  background: #FFF;
  border: 1px solid #d5d5d6;
  outline: none;
  color: #96999D;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  border-radius: 4px;
  transition: all 0.15s;
}

input[type=checkbox]:focus {
  border-color: #ACACB8;
  color: #2E3236;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.18)!important;
}

div {
    border: 1px inset #ccc;
    border-radius: 7px;
    margin: 1em;
    padding: 1em;
}

#webkitCheckbox {
    -webkit-appearance: checkbox;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <span>This has <code>-webkit-appearance: none;</code></span>
    </label>
</div>

<div>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="webkitCheckbox" />
        <span>This has <code>-webkit-appearance: checkbox;</code></span>
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: When you set it to none, it disables the standard appearance (checkbox). You could specify your inputs by just saying `input[type=text] { -webkit-appearance: none; }`.

Comment: I don't want to display the standard appearance checkbox. I want to display my custom version with the CSS applied but when I do that, I lose the functionality of the checkbox.

Comment: I have fixed this and answered this here
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78216387/13945107)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You just nuked all styles of checkbox on WebKit, so yes you can't see whether they're checked or not (they still are, it just isn't visible to us sighted people without a screen reader).

You need to style the checked state with the `:checked` pseudo: **http://jsfiddle.net/VWC76/450/**

```
input[type=checkbox]:checked {
    background-color: red;
    /* or whatever styles you want depending on your design */
    /* be as obvious as possible that it's a checkbox and that it's checked! */
}
```

EDIT:

- `appearance:none` now exists outside of WebKit/Blink ([caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=appearance)). Just use [Autoprefixer](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer) if you've better to do than adding prefixes by hand :)
- A good implementation: [accessible custom checkbox and radio form controls](http://filamentgroup.github.io/checkboxradio/)

EDIT 2:

- in the fiddle demo, adding focusable elements before and after checkbox to show it works with keyboard (just click on the first occurence of "Test" and then tab tab space tab). It lacks any visual cue that checkbox/label is focused which is a bad thing (it's a demo). *Best seen on Chrome* which is a worse thing :p (you need Autoprefixer. Try on Codepen)

Comment: Lol.  I'm here cause I too, without realizing, pressed the big red launch nuke button. Luckily I didn't cause any damage =P

Comment: The example is not accessible. It's completely unusable with a keyboard.

Comment: @Webveloper Only in JSFiddle (it's a complex mix of iframes,hard to use with a keyboard except if you click in the correct iframe…) or anywhere? I added focusable elements and an edit explanation: it works.

Answer (score 5):

You need to add a input[type=checkbox]:checked

```
input[type=checkbox]:checked {
   background: #BADA55;
}
```

If this is what you're looking for?

Comment: @AidanMiles Pretty close to a zombie green ;)

Answer (score 3):

Disabling the appearance removes the checked appearance too. You also need to add styles to define how the checkbox will appear when checked.

```
input[type='checkbox']:checked
{
    position:relative;
}
input[type='checkbox']:checked:before
{
    content:'';
    display:block;
    width:17px;
    height:16px;
    position:absolute;
    top:1px;
    left:1px;
    background:none #ACACB8;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    opacity:0.5;
}
```

Check out the fiddle below for an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/8n8hM/

Comment: Beware that `:before` pseudo on an `input` works *for now* and may not work in a future (or not so future) version of Blink/WebKit. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4660434/137626) for reference and also Jukka K. Korpela's answer. I'd make sure that the checked input gets some style, a style hidden by the one set by `:before`

Answer (score 1):

The best way to personnalize `checkbox` or radio button that works cross browser is by using `label` that you set for your `checkbox`.
In your css, you hide your `checkbox` and you add any style you want for the label.

```css
input[type='checkbox'] {
    outline: 0;
    user-select: none;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
}
input[type='checkbox'] + label {
    display:inline-block;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    background-color:blue
}
input[type='checkbox']:checked + label {
    background-color:red
}
```

```html
<input id="myChk" type="checkbox" />
<label for="myChk">&nbsp</label>
```

See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VWC76/705/).

Comment: by current browser standards, for the protection of the user, any input box rendered invisible, off screen, or inaccessible, is not submitted with the form values. This example removes the checkbox from display, and removes its value from submission.

Comment: Never had problem using this. Do you have any official links?